# %3F instead of question mark in my Retrofit URL

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a picture to a server. My URL contains some parameters about my phone:

```
api/v2/user/email_register%3F_height=1184&_target=android/2&_width=768
```

and this is the working variant:

```
api/v2/user/email_register?_height=1184&_target=android/2&_width=768
```

(without irritation %3? code)

Also, I'm trying to pass my picture inside @Body:

```
@POST("/{url}")
Observable<UpdateUserInfoPayload> register(
        @Header("x-device-id") String deviceId,
        @Body RequestBody requestBody,
        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) String  method
);
```

Creating it with MultipartBuilder:

```
protected RequestBody buildAvatar(String avatarPath) {


 MultipartBuilder builder = new MultipartBuilder()
  .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_NAME, name.getText().toString())
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_SECOND_NAME, lastName.getText().toString())
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_EMAIL, email.getText().toString())
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_ENCODED_PASSWORD,
   PasswordUtils.encodePassword(encodePassword()))
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_GENDER,
   male.isChecked() ? EmailProfile.GENDER_MALE : EmailProfile.GENDER_FEMALE)
  .addFormDataPart(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_PARSE_ID,
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId());


 File file = new File(avatarPath);;
 int size = (int) file.length();
 byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
 try {
  BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
  buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  buf.close();
  builder.addFormDataPart("photo", "image.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, bytes));
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return builder.build();
}
```

That is why I'm unable to use for example:

```
@FieldMap Map<String, String> params
```

to pass my parameters there, because @FieldMap requires @FormUrlEncoded while I'm unable to make @Body request with @FormUrlEncoded.

1)How to remove %3F from my URL String? (outside retrofit everythin is fine!)

2)Is there any easy way to send a picture?

**UPD:**
 <-- 403 Forbidden https://api.example.com/api/v2/user/5984/validate_password
when I use @Field annotation:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/{url}")
Observable<BooleanResponse> validatePassword(
        @Header("x-device-id") String deviceId,
        @Field(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_ENCODED_PASSWORD) String password,
        @Field(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_HEIGHT) String height,
        @Field(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_WIDTH) String width,
        @Field(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_TARGET) String target,

        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) String  method
);
```

Everything works when I use it like that:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/v2/user/5984/validate_password?_height=1184&_target=android%2F2&_width=768&_user_id=5984") //full url
    Observable<BooleanResponse> validatePassword(
            @Header("x-device-id") String deviceId,
            @Field(ParkApiUrl.PARAM_USER_ENCODED_PASSWORD) String password
    );
```

I want either to remove %3F or learn how to use Field in POST request without getting FORBIDDEN

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit won't let you put the query string in the path. Take a look at [@QueryMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html) instead, which is designed for this.

Comment: I still want to get rid of this %3F and put a question mark. Any ideas?

Comment: You also can see this https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html

Answer (score 1):

As refs: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html

I use `@QueryMap` and `ImmutableMap`.

In my case, the API is: `/api/static_pages/?q=A+B+C`

My solution:

Step 1:

```
@GET("/api/static_pages")
    Call<String> getStaticPagesByType(@HeaderMap HashMap<String, Object> header,
                               @QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, String> filters);
```

Step 2:  When I want to call API:

```
List<String> listTypes = new ArrayList<>();
listTypes.add("A");
listTypes.add("B");
listTypes.add("C");

StringBuilder typeString = new StringBuilder();

int listSize = listType.size();

for (int i = 0; i < listSize - 1; i++) {
    typeString.append(listType.get(i));
    if(i != listSize-2){
       typeString.append("+");
    }
}
// The key is here!
ImmutableMap<String, String> types = ImmutableMap.of("q", typeString.toString());
getRetrofitClient().getStaticPagesByType(yourHeader, types)
```

Hope it help your work.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by `@QueryName`
It allows you to attach `?` sign at the end of the Url and then the string you want after "?" Sign
You may also need to look at `@QueryName(encoded = true)` if your string is already encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The better idea is, Make a multi part request for sending images

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/v2/user/email_register")
Observable<UpdateUserInfoPayload> register(@Part("_height") String height, @Part("_target") String target, @Part("_width") String width, @Part("imageFile") TypedFile file);
```

ref: https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-how-to-upload-files#introduction

No need to add/remove %3F in retrofit it will automatically handle

Comment: Use a RequestBody from version 2.+

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a dynamic URL String that contains path and query parameters you should use `@Url`  [Retrofit @Url](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Url.html)

```
@POST(
Observable<UpdateUserInfoPayload> register(
        @Header("x-device-id") String deviceId,
        @Body RequestBody requestBody,
        @Url String method
);
```

where `method = api/v2/user/email_register?_height=1184&_target=android/2&_width=768`

Then, the request will look like:

```
https://api.example.com/api/v2/user/email_register?_height=1184&_target=android/2&_width=768
```